# Jruby 1.6 + Rails 3 and Java servlet session store issue

Tags: jruby, rails-3-upgrade

I am upgrading from JRuby 1.5 to JRuby 1.6.3 and Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3.0.

Earlier, I used to use:

```
ActionController::Base.session_store = :java_servlet_store if defined?($servlet_context)
```

in config/initializers/session_store.rb

Now in the same file I do:

```
Mb30::Application.config.session_store = :java_servlet_store if defined?($servlet_context)
```

The earlier version in Production used to yield `jsessionid` and work
well with session. Since I used the Java servlet store in Tomcat, I used the
default session timeout feature in `web.xml`, and it worked very well.

However after upgrading I see in Firebug that there is a `jsession` id
created. but at the same time there is a Rails `_session_id` also created
and killing the `jsessionid` doesn't kill the Rails session id . Also I
have an HTTP wrapper API over my application which gets response and
sends it as xml. Here I figured that the `jsessionid` is not matching the
Rails session due to which in the API I am unable to get the session
objects since they are getting set in Rails session.

Here are my Gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0)
actionpack (3.0.0)
activemodel (3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.0)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (0.9.7 java)
activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter (0.9.7 java)
activeresource (3.0.0)
activesupport (3.0.0)
arel (1.0.0)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.18)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.4.1)
jdbc-postgres (8.4.701 java)
jrails (0.6.0)
jruby-jars (1.6.3)
jruby-openssl (0.7.2, 0.7)
jruby-rack (1.1.1, 1.0.10)
mail (2.2.5)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.12)
rack-test (0.5.4)
rails (3.0.0)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
sources (0.0.1)
thor (0.14.0)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.29, 0.3.23)
warbler (1.2.0)
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue here could be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `Mb30::Application` is your Rails application, which is itself a subclass of `Rails::Application`, so the configuration setting probably isn't making its way out to `ActionController::Base`.

Try adding this to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.session_store = :java_servlet_store
```

As well as setting up an initializer for the session store in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
Mb30::Application.config.session_store :java_servlet_store
```

The initializer may not be necessary; I've used this when setting up a custom DB session store, as I ran into a similar problem.

Comment: I tried that, still to no avail. Its still behaving as a Cookie store and calling Set Cookie all the time